# How to display empty cell in React Native FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to make a flatlist that have exact 4 columns and if the data is lower than 4 items in a row, to show empty cell. How can I make it display empty cell?

Here is my Flatlist:

```
            <FlatList
                key={list.title}
                data={list.rooms}
                style={styles.scheduleContainer}
                horizontal={false}
                numColumns={4}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderItemSeparator}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                  console.log('item', item.room);
                  return (
                    <View style={styles.elementsContainer}>
                        <Text>
                            {item.room.data.name}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
            />
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Here is the result I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: just use flex and divide it based on row item, fill data as per column, if not available return empty view. for eg.
first row have 4 item
flex will be 0.25 to each item
now in next item is 3 item so flex
is 0.25.each but 3 is filled and one is empty but with flex 0.25

Comment: Can you show an example please?